# Forzar un refresh a la base de datos con Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Quería saber como forzar una actualización de la base de datos local que trae c# sin tener que detener la compilación, ya que me trae los datos,pero una lista anterior al inserción de los datos.

```
   private void btnAñadirDet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Carta cart = new Carta();
        PedidosDetalles clas = new PedidosDetalles();
  
        
        using (resBDE db = new resBDE())
        {

            IQueryable<PedidosDetalles> kek = db.PedidosDetalles.AsNoTracking().Where(d => d.IdUser == idUser && d.Detalles == txtPedido.Text).Distinct(); 
           car.Actualizar(idUser,txtPedido.Text);
           int cont =car.SO;          
       


            if (cont > 0)   
            {
                foreach (PedidosDetalles a in kek)
                {
                    if (a.Detalles != txtPedido.Text)
                    {
                        clas.Detalles = txtPedido.Text;
                        clas.Precio = Int32.Parse(txtPrecio.Text);
                        clas.Cantidad = Int32.Parse(txtCantidad.Text);
                        clas.IdUser = idUser;
                        car.InsertarDetalles(clas);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (a.Detalles == txtPedido.Text)
                    {
                        clas.Detalles = txtPedido.Text;
                        clas.Cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(txtCantidad.Text);
                        car.EditarDetalles(clas);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }  
            if(cont == 0) {

                clas.Detalles = txtPedido.Text;
                clas.Precio = Int32.Parse(txtPrecio.Text);
                clas.Cantidad = Int32.Parse(txtCantidad.Text);
                clas.IdUser = idUser;                  
                car.InsertarDetalles(clas);
           
            }
      

        }
       

        this.Close();
        cart.Detalles(idUser);
    }
```

Comment: qué base de datos usas?

Comment: Estoy ocupando la base de datos local que trae C#.

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822